# How can I prevent a click at the end of a note?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I wrote the following code to play a note with a contoured lowpass filter:

```js
    var ac = new AudioContext;

    var master = ac.createGain();
    master.connect(ac.destination);
    master.gain.value = 0.7;

    var filter = ac.createBiquadFilter();
    filter.connect(master);
    filter.type = 'lowpass';
    filter.Q.value = 2;

    var osc = ac.createOscillator();
    osc.connect(filter);
    osc.type = 'square';
    osc.frequency.value = 55;

    var now = ac.currentTime;
    osc.start(now);
    //osc.stop(now+0.2);
    filter.frequency.setValueAtTime(0, now);
    filter.frequency.linearRampToValueAtTime(440, now+0.02);
    filter.frequency.linearRampToValueAtTime(0, now+0.12);
```

The note sounds as expected (the filter opens quickly, then completely closes a bit more slowly) but at the very end of it I can hear a click. The lower the note, the louder the click.

I already tried uncommenting the commented line, as well as adding a contour to the master, but nothing worked.

**Edit:** By "adding contour to the master" I mean I tried ramping down the master gain to 0 *exactly* at  the same time as the filter reaches 0. This would not work.

How can I prevent the click at the end of the note?

Comment: After fiddling with your example a bit, it seems that stopping the oscillator a little **earlier** than the filter fixes the click. I'm not sure why, I tried snapping it to various points along the wave period but that doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While, intuitively, lowering a filter to zero should cut off all signal, filters don't "cut off" all signal above the specified frequency. So you should expect some energy to be in the signal even with the filter you've created.

However, filters DO cut off signal in direct proportion to how far those signals are from the cutoff frequency. So it makes perfect sense that, the lower your signal is, the louder the pop of turning it off is (because lower frequencies are closer to your cutoff of zero and therefore less attenuated by the filter).

You can solve this problem by doing a linear ramp of the GAIN of the signal immediately before you schedule the signal to stop altogether. You can ramp down in the last millisecond or so in order to avoid a pop.

Answer (score 0):

Describe what "adding a contour to the master" means.

In your example, I would ramp down the master gain to zero just before the filter frequency goes to 0.

Comment: Actually, what you propose really does the trick! I edited my question, maybe you want to edit your answer a little bit, too?